# lrm and orm contrast rms package

Tags: r, regression, logistic, regression-strategies, ordered-logit

I am using `rms` and can't understand the difference between `orm` and `lrm` when used with `contrasts`. For example:

```
x <- factor(rbinom(100,2,0.6), labels = c("a","b","c"), ordered = TRUE)
y <- factor(rbinom(100,1,0.5), labels=c("no","yes"))
l <- lrm(x~y)
l

Logistic Regression Model

lrm(formula = x ~ y)
                     Model Likelihood     Discrimination    Rank Discrim.    
                        Ratio Test            Indexes          Indexes       
Obs           100    LR chi2      0.51    R2       0.006    C       0.529    
 a             24    d.f.            1    g        0.133    Dxy     0.059    
 b             40    Pr(> chi2) 0.4764    gr       1.143    gamma   0.117    
 c             36                         gp       0.024    tau-a   0.039    
max |deriv| 1e-10                         Brier    0.181                     

      Coef    S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
y>=b   1.0188 0.2988  3.41  0.0007  
y>=c  -0.7162 0.2884 -2.48  0.0130  
y=yes  0.2642 0.3715  0.71  0.4769

o <- orm(x~y)
l;o

Logistic (Proportional Odds) Ordinal Regression Model

orm(formula = x ~ y)
                     Model Likelihood          Discrimination          Rank Discrim.    
                        Ratio Test                 Indexes                Indexes       
Obs           100    LR chi2      0.51    R2                  0.006    rho     0.071    
 a             24    d.f.            1    g                   0.133                     
 b             40    Pr(> chi2) 0.4764    gr                  1.143                     
 c             36    Score chi2   0.51    |Pr(Y>=median)-0.5| 0.259                     
Unique Y        3    Pr(> chi2) 0.4766                                                  
Median Y        2                                                                       
max |deriv| 7e-05                                                                       

      Coef    S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
y>=b   1.0188 0.2988  3.41  0.0007  
y>=c  -0.7162 0.2884 -2.48  0.0130  
y=yes  0.2642 0.3715  0.71  0.4769
```

We can see, that results of `orm` and `lrm` are equal. But when we use `contrasts` the results are different:

```
contrast(l,list(y="no"),list(y="yes"))

     Contrast      S.E.      Lower     Upper     Z Pr(>|z|)
11 -0.2642454 0.3714673 -0.9923081 0.4638172 -0.71   0.4769
Confidence intervals are 0.95 individual intervals
```

and

```
contrast(o,list(y="no"),list(y="yes"))

Contrast      S.E.      Lower   Upper    Z Pr(>|z|)
11 0.7545878 0.3714672 0.02652544 1.48265 2.03   0.0422

Confidence intervals are 0.95 individual intervals
```

Why `orm` contrast aren't equal beta regression coefficient as `lrm` contrast?

Answer (score 1):

This is a significant error that has now been fixed on github and will be in the next release to CRAN.  It's best to report `rms` package issues through https://github.com/harrelfe/rms.  But thanks for reporting the error.  You can get a temporary fix by typing

```
require(rms)
getRs('contrast.s', grepo='rms', dir='R', put='source')
```